# mysql show tables in order by referenced_table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Anybody knows what is the query to list all tables by `"show tables"` or by `"information_schema"` in order by referenced tables?

Like:

```
SELECT *  FROM `TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` LIKE 'db_name' ORDER BY
REFERENCED_TABLE
```

because tables are listed in alphabetical order. I want it by mother_tables first listed then child_tables is the next.

Comment: what do you mean by `mother_tables` and `child_tables` ?

Comment: There may not be a well-defined order... tables can reference multiple other tables; circularities may even exist.  How could one sort the results in such a case?

Comment: i mean that mother_tables are tables with no foreign keys and child_tables have foreign keys..

i want to duplicate a database : CREATE DATABASE db_name LIKE old_db

but apparently, it wont work so i have to create database first then create tables : CREATE TABLE db_name.table_name LIKE old_db.table

problem is when the child table is created first.

Comment: @eggyal it can be true that circularities may exist and the only solution ive come-up to circularities is create the tables first then alter it. but for the moment, my current db is not circular.

Comment: i see ... then you need to use `REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` table

Comment: and how do i do that? how i query that the mother_tables and child_tables are all listed? REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS only list the child_tables.